# SQL- How to get last record for each account

Tags: sql

I have two tables Member and Discount. I am looking to retrieve last recordnumber row for each account. Is there a way to do this?

Sample data from Discount table

[image]

Sample Data Member table

[image]

```
enter code here
```

Desired output

```
enter code here
```

[image]

```
enter code here
```

SQL query that I tried but it doesn't return the desired result:

```
SELECT 
    Max(a.recordnumber)
    , a.account
    , d.NAME
    , d.memberid
    , a.effectivedate
    , a.amount 
 FROM 
    member m 
    LEFT JOIN discount d ON m.account on d.account;
```

Comment: SQL query that I tried but it doesn't return the desired result

SELECT    Max(a.recordnumber),
          a.account,
          d.NAME d.memberid,
          a.effectivedate,
          a.amount
FROM      member m
LEFT JOIN discount d
ON        m.account
on        d.account;

Comment: 9/1/2019, is that 9:th of January, or September 1:st? Column data type?

Comment: September 1st...MM/DD/YY

Comment: Thank you jarlh. I am looking for the last RecordNumber row for each Member. Last record number for John Doe is 3 and that's what I am interested in. Date is kind of not important in this case. Just need the last recordnumber row for each member

Comment: Sorry, multitasking error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have somewhat different functionality that can be used here.)

Comment: Its intersystems cache database uses the Java drivers.Cache Objects Version 2018.1.2.309 Cache xDBC Server 8.01
InterSystems Cache JDBC
2016.2.1.803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table `member` to a query that returns the last row of each account in table `discount`:

```
select d.recordnum, m.account, m.name, m.memberid, d.effectivedate, d.amount
from member m left join (
  select d.* from discount d
  where not exists (
    select 1 from discount
    where account = d.account and recordnum > d.recordnum
  )
) d on d.account = m.account
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question, I think something like this might do it:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.recordnumber
        , a.account
        , d.NAME
        , d.memberid
        , a.effectivedate
        , a.amount 
     FROM 
        member m 
        LEFT JOIN discount d ON m.account on d.account
     ORDER BY a.recordnumber
) inner
```

That will get you only one record. If you end up with the first record instead of the last, then change

```
ORDER BY a.recordnumber
```

to:

```
ORDER BY a.recordnumber DESC
```